# Tar header contains invalid size

Tags: heimdall

I've been trying to open a `.tar.md5` file containing a cellphone software update using [Heimdall](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755265) under Mac OSX Snow Leopard.  The file was extracted from a `.zip` downloaded from [sammobile.com](http://sammobile.com) containing these files:

```
S7562XXALHB_S7562ATOALH1_S7562XXLH5.tar.md5 (921.1 MB)
SS_DLL (279 KB)
```

I keep getting an invalid size error. I have tried re-downloading it several times as well as other files just to check and still the same error.

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what OS, what tar and what unzip command, what command line options, what error message text and the file name, size and perhaps other details, like where you got it.

Comment: Can you tell i'm a noob? :)  Mac OS X Snow Leopard; the tar is a cellphone software update S7562XXALHB_S7562ATOALH1_S7562XXLH5.tar.md5 (921.1 MB) and is in a zip file with other file being SS_DLL (279 KB). The zip was downloaded from sammobile.com.

Comment: The ending `md5` tells that this is just the md5sum of the real file, which possibly ends with `tar.gz` or `tar.bz2`.

Comment: Thanks, Nicole. Definately looks better than what I had. :)

So how do actually get to the .tar.gzha file from the .md5? I don't see that anywhere. The .md5 is the only .tar file that generates from the zip file.